# What is a word for a piece of cultural heritage?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something that could be a book, a video, a song, an idiom, and so on - anything that someone might consider a piece of their culture. This is in the context of uploads to a website but I am trying to avoid using something generic like "file". I thought of "artifact" but that seems to imply something old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artifact/artefact, used in conjunction with *Cultural*, does not necessarily means something old, according to [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_artifact) (emphasis mine):

> Cultural artifact is a more generic term and should be considered with
> two words of similar, but narrower, nuance: social artifact and
> archaeological artifact. **Cultural artifacts** can include objects
> recovered from archaeological sites, or archaeological artifacts, but
> **can also include objects of modern or near-modern society,** or social
> artifacts. For example, in an anthropological context: a 17th-century
> lathe, a piece of faience, or a **television** each provides a wealth of
> information about the time in which they were manufactured and used.

So I'd suggest **Cultural artifact**

Comment: Assuming that you want to convey that this item was created by the culture, "cultural artifact" is just the thing. If you wish to convey that the item is important to a person, "keepsake" or "heritage" might be more what you seek.